# Итерация nodeType и nodeValue

Tags: javascript

В чем проблема при итерации nodeType и nodeValue? Почему эти и другие некоторые свойства не итерируются, хотя другие итерируются?

```js
let item = document.querySelector('#elem');
let child = item.nodeType
for (let i of child) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">
  txt
  <b>tag</b>
  <!--com-->
  txt
  <b>tag</b>
  <!--com-->
</div>
```

Comment: какой результат ты ожидаешь в своем примере?

Comment: вывод типов всех узлов. нужно использовать наверное метод чилдрен но незнаю как

Comment: `nodeType` свойство типа `Number`, `nodeValue` - `String | null`. `Number`, то есть цифра не является перечислением, чтобы "итерироваться", а из `String | null` "итерироваться" может только `String`, то есть строка, получая символы по отдельности.

Comment: Меняйте в `for(const child of item.childNodes) { console.log(child.nodeType) }` будет работать. Но советую ещё раз прочитать то что вы написали в вашем вопросе. Оно совершенно не соответствует задачу который вы хотите получить, к тому же сформулировано плохо.

Answer (score 0):

[`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) - это число, показывающее тип узла (элемент, текст и т.д.)

Если нужно получить дочерние узлы, вместо этого нужно использовать либо [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) либо [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) (только элементы)

```js
let item = document.querySelector('#elem');


let child = item.childNodes;

for (let i of child) {
  console.log(i.textContent)
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">txt<b>tag</b>
  <!--com-->txt<b>tag</b>
  <!--com-->
</div>
```